# Geneos monitoring tool and IIS server

Tags: windows, monitoring, iis-8, geneos

We're using ITRS Geneos monitoring tool at work for monitoring server clusters and its services.

My question though - would it be possible to somehow configure Geneos to monitor the IIS servers and its websites + app pools.

Lets say - an app pool / website suddenly shuts off and Geneos would therefor alarm us.

If so - how would one go for configuring this?

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebMon plugin to monitor the serverstatus and the Website pages.

you can also explore EUEM plugin for more active website monitoring.